# Jquery Conflict issue for slider tab not working for second tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery carousel tab slider for my project. But i am getting some issue, that is when I click on the Featured products the slider goes down and stops working.

Please see [link](http://dev.genuusdemo.com/bigbazaar/) for your reference

Also see the js fiddle for the html [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sq2pys5y/)

See the JScode:-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    addOnload(function () {
        BIGB.utils.runOnload();
    });
    addWindowOnload(function () {
        BIGB.utils.runWindowOnload();
    });
    require_module.init({ "carousel": { "url": "slider/carousel-e1e730d.js" } });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    require_module.js("carousel", function () {
        $(".require-nav-carousel").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var params = {
                content: $('.ccarousel', $this),
                buttonOverlap: true,
                sliderOverlap: true
            };
            var parsed_params = $this.data();
            $.extend(params, parsed_params);
            var navCarousel = new BIGB.ui.Carousel(params);
            navCarousel.init();
            $this.removeClass("require-nav-carousel");
        });
    });
    BIGB.linkTracking.setContext("hp");
    $('.bannerHolder').each(function () {
        $(this).mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hoverIn').removeClass('hoverOut').removeClass('noTransition');
        }).mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).addClass('hoverOut').removeClass('hoverIn').addClass('noTransition');
        });
    });
    (function () {
        var $window = $(window);
        $window.bind('scroll', _.throttle(enableChristmasSaleUnit, 200));
        $window.bind('resize', _.throttle(enableChristmasSaleUnit, 200));
        var $saleUnit = $('.sticky-unit');
        function enableChristmasSaleUnit() {
            requestAnimFrame(function () {
                var st = $window.scrollTop();
                if (st > 200) {
                    !$saleUnit.hasClass("sticky-unit-active") && $saleUnit.addClass("sticky-unit-active");
                } else {
                    $saleUnit.hasClass("sticky-unit-active") && $saleUnit.removeClass("sticky-unit-active");
                }
            });
        }
    })();

</script>
```

See below the Image for error
[image: Error Image]

Comment: do u have any console errors..?

Comment: @Outlooker: yes, I have the error as " Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: which scripts are causing the conflicts..??

Comment: @Outlooker: `$('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({` this is the line where it is giving the error

Comment: Are you using 2 versions of jQuery..??

Comment: You need to find a way to refresh or reload the carousel on tab select as the tab is hidden so the calculated width is 0

Comment: @Outlooker: See how many versions I am using `   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` Let me know which one is best to use..

Comment: @anpsmn: Can you please tell the way or some hint related to it ?

Comment: @NadeemKhan The plugin will be having few methods to refresh it. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: @anpsmn: I am using many versions of Jquery to work it out

Comment: @NadeemKhan Am talking about the carousel plugin.

Comment: @anpsmn: I am using `carousel-e1e730d.js` plugin which is mentioned in the js code

Comment: @NadeemKhan I wanted the plugin name so that we can find from their documentation. The `carousel-e1e730d.js` has the plugin name commented [http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). Try reload from theeir [documentation](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/api.html#reload)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70762/discussion-between-nadeem-khan-and-anpsmn).

Comment: @anpsmn: I have something like this `require_module.init({ "carousel": { "url": "slider/carousel-e1e730d.js" } });` how to reload from their now ??

Comment: @NadeemKhan `carousel-e1e730d.js` is a minfied js. If you [beautify](http://jsbeautifier.org/), you will find there is a code written after the jcarousel code. So looking at that you can use reset or reinit. The issue is reinit has unbind which works in older jquery I guess. Best for you is to add a carousel plugin directly than use a custom js from other site.

Comment: @anpsmn: Can you help me how to add the carousel directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use multiple version of jQuery ,try the following solution mate.. :)

```
<!-- load jQuery 2.2.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery221 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.10 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery110 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Then use the desired plugin with the desired jQuery version..

Comment: I am not using 2.2.1.js ? Will it be mine versions and should I check with that ?